# Topological properties under the Lipschitz map

Tags: general-topology

Let $G: E\to F$ be the Lipschitz map, i.e., there exist $c>0$
such that 
$$c^{-1}|x-y|\leq|G(x)-G(y)|\leq c|x-y|$$
for any $x,y\in E$
where $E\,,F\in\mathbb{R^n}$
then E and F have many same properties, for instance, if E has an interior then F also has interior. If E has positive lebesgue measures, then F also has positive lebesgue measures. how can we prove this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $f$ instead of $G$. If $E$ has a point $e$ such that $B_{e,r}\subset E$ for some $r>0$, then by the Lipschiz inequality you given we have $$B_{f(e),c^{-1}r}\subset f(B_{e,r})\subset B_{f(e),cr}$$for example. So if $E$ has an non-empty interior then so is $f(E)$, and since $f$ is $1-1$ from $E$ to $f(E)$, the reverse conclusion also holds.

I leave the conclusion of positive measure to you, the proof is similar.